# Trying to connect Cashfree Payment Gateway to a Form

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, payment

We run a WordPress site at wildleaf.in and have this Pay with Cashfree link at (https://wildleaf.in/3488-2/)

Is there a way where I can write an HTML form or connect a WordPress form plugin to this gateway?

Example: https://eclinic.savikalpa.com/book (this has the Paytm gateway)

I want to basically collect the same details

```
<h3>Pay ₹ 500</h3>
<div class="book-1st-set-div">
<div class="form-2-column">
<div class="form-div no-margins"><label class="field-label white" for="Name-5">First name:</label> <input id="Name-5" class="dark-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="patient_first_name" required="" type="text" placeholder="Patient's first name&hellip;" data-name="Name" /></div>
<div class="form-div no-margins"><label class="field-label white" for="Name-6">Last Name:</label> <input id="Name-6" class="dark-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="patient_last_name" required="" type="text" placeholder="Patient's last name&hellip;" data-name="Name 6" /></div>
</div>
<div class="form-2-column">
<div class="form-div no-margins"><label class="field-label white" for="Name-8">Email:</label> <input id="Email-6" class="dark-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="patient_email" required="" type="email" placeholder="Patient's email&hellip;" data-name="Email 6" /></div>
<div class="form-div no-margins"><label class="field-label white" for="Name-9">Mobile:</label> <input id="Phone-2" class="dark-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="patient_mobile" required="" type="tel" placeholder="Patient's mobile&hellip;" data-name="Phone 2" /></div>
</div>
<div class="form-2-column">
<div class="form-div no-margins"><label class="field-label white" for="Name-7">Date of birth:</label> <input id="Email-4" class="dark-field w-input" max="2003-09-14" maxlength="256" name="patient_date_of_birth" required="" type="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" data-name="Email 4" /></div>
<div class="form-div no-margins"><label class="field-label white" for="Name-7">weight:</label> <input id="Email-4" class="dark-field w-input" maxlength="256" name="patient_weight" required="" type="number" placeholder="eg. 60 KG" data-name="Email 4" /></div>
</div>
<div class="form-2-column">
<div class="form-div no-margins"><label class="field-label white" for="Name-8">gender:</label>
<div class="gender-div"><label class="radio-button-field w-radio"> <input id="Male" class="w-form-formradioinput w-radio-input" name="patient_gender" type="radio" value="M" data-name="Gender" /><span class="radio-text white w-form-label">Male</span> </label> <label class="radio-button-field w-radio"> <input id="Female" class="w-form-formradioinput w-radio-input" name="patient_gender" type="radio" value="F" data-name="Gender" /> <span class="radio-text white w-form-label">Female</span> </label> <label class="radio-button-field w-radio"> <input id="Other" class="w-form-formradioinput w-radio-input" name="patient_gender" type="radio" value="O" data-name="Gender" /> <span class="radio-text white w-form-label">Other</span> </label></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="align-right-btns"><button class="cancel-btns" type="button">CANCEL</button> <button class="proceed-btns" type="submit">PROCEED</button> <input name="pageID" type="hidden" value="3488" /></div>
```

Can someone help me out here? Ready to connect and discuss as well.

Comment: Ask the payment gateway if they can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cashfree came up with a Gravity form integration.

Here are the steps to get started

1. Download the form file from the [github repo here](https://github.com/wp-premium/gravityforms).
2. Download Cashfree Add on from [here](https://github.com/cashfree/cashfree-gravity-forms)
3. Upload both these plugins to your wordpress backend either by using the upload option in the plugin section or using FTP options onto the plugins folder.
4. Activate the plugins
5. Create your gravity form with necessary fields and add the section option for payment and define the price & add a total column as well.
6. Under gravity form settings you can see cashfree option. (Setup with your necessary keys and set the currency to your desired option)
7. Add the form to your desired page and start accepting payments.

**Note**: Gravity form is a paid plugin kindly visit their website for pricing details.